# Excel: Is there a formula for this big space in between another?

Tags: excel, formula, trim

I have content which looks like this below in the excel. i need to trim away all the unnecessary info. Only keep the -.pdf. The remaining will be removed.
i have tried several formula but only able to get the first document name.

`1-Abc.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff`





`2-Def.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff`





`3-Ghi.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff`





`4-Jkl.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff`

I need a formula which i able to get the final result like this below.

`1-Abc.pdf`
`2-Def.pdf`
`3-Ghi.pdf`
`4-Jkl.pdf`

Please help.

Comment: Tried but no none of the formula works

Comment: Is there an excel that deals with big spaces in between data specially i am facing? the Data are in one cell. Not 4 lines in 4 different cells.

Answer (score 1):

Return everything before the first space character:

```
=left(A1, find(" ",A1&" ")-1)
```

This formula also works if there is no space in the source text.

Comment: thanks but the format i have is with spaces...

Comment: What I meant is that the formula I posted works without error on a cell value like "1-Abc.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff" but also on a value like "1-Abc.pdf" - It returns all text before the first space. Data is not always perfect, so maybe in some cells there is just the filename. The formula I suggested will not return an error message, just because no space exists.

Answer (score 0):

If the end of the text is always " is a pdf containing important stuff", you could use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A1, LEN(A1) - 36)
```

Make sure you replace "A1" with the reference to the cell you need to extract the value from.

Comment: works only for the 1 line "1-Abc.pdf"

Comment: The reference to cell 'A1' needs to be changed in order for the formula to work for another cell.  Copy and pasting the formula cell so it's next to the second, third and nth value.

Comment: The sample are in one cell. Not four different cells.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the document name regardless of the text string after that.

```
=LEFT(A1; FIND(".pdf";A1)+4)
```

Comment: Be aware that a lot of systems out there use the comma, not the semicolon as the list separator. The semicolon is typically used in European settings. US and UK normally use the comma.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I only able to get the first line which is "1-Abc.pdf"

Comment: Have you changed both of the cell references in the formula?

Comment: yes, but only one is truncated.